# No PopUp Context Helpert

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I installed anaconda and created a virtualenv which contains jupyter.
I started writing code. But I was supposed to get context helper popup, and actually I don't.
For example, I write this python line:

```
s = 'string';
```

And then

```
s.
```

I was expecting to get a pop-up showing all the related methods. This does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the pop-up to appear you will need to hit the TAB key.

It's also important to note that the context helper is an IPython feature, so make sure you are running `ipython` and not `python` if you are using the command line.